# Error trying use duplicity for backups

Tags: rackspace-cloudfiles, duplicity

I was asked to help with broken backup script on legacy system.
There is a script file on server which should run hourly to put DB backup to Rackspace cloud. And here is the result.

```
START cf-postgresql-dump ...
Wed 04 Nov 2015 06:49:09 AM EST

Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
Download of 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' failed (attempt 1): CloudFiles returned: 404 Not Found
Download of 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' failed (attempt 2): CloudFiles returned: 404 Not Found
Download of 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' failed (attempt 3): CloudFiles returned: 404 Not Found
Download of 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' failed (attempt 4): CloudFiles returned: 404 Not Found
Download of 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' failed (attempt 5): CloudFiles returned: 404 Not Found
Giving up downloading 'duplicity-full-signatures.20130622T180407Z.sigtar.gpg' after 5 attempts
```

what is the source of the problem and what is the way to fix it?
As I can see there is a missing file on our backup storage so we cannot produce incremental backup. Am I right?

Comment: We have not changed the API.  If you think that an object is missing that should be there, I would advise creating a support ticket so we can look into the issue.  Also supplying a transaction ID and/or time of object creation in the ticket is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

smells like the cf backend is broken. probably some changes in the cf API.

try to update to the latest duplicity 0.6.x or 0.7.x and retry.

..ede/duply.net